# Set stack limit on WSL2 permanently

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I permanently change the stack size in WSL2 Ubuntu? I can temporarily change the size with:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

But that only lasts till the session is closed. I have tried adding these lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
* soft stack unlimited
* hard stack unlimited
```

But that does not change the stack limit as reported by `ulimit -a`.

I can call `ulimit -s unlimited` in `.bashrc`, but that won't work for non-interactive shells.

Strangely, if I `su` to my own user with `su user`, the stack appears as unlimited! It is only when I open the shell where it appears to have some default of 8192.

Comment: Did you logout and login again after changing `limits.conf`?

Comment: Indeed I have logged in and out again after changing `limits.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/security/limits.conf` are used by [pam_limits](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_limits.8.html). You need to authenticate via ssh, su, sudo, for [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) and `limits.conf` file to be taken in consideration.

I see as alternative to set the limits in ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc
Also in those file you can export BASH_ENV to point to a file similar to bashrc for non-interactive shells.

E.g. for `~/.bashrc`:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
export BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc-non-interactive
```

And in `~/.bashrc-non-interactive`:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

For more details: [Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)